# How Configure AngularJs with spring MVC and Spring Web Flow

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

At present im new developper with angularJs, please can anyone explain me by example how to configure AngularJs with Spring MVC and Web Flow ? (web.xml and pom.xml)

Thank you for advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular is a presentation layer on the client side. It is not really meant to integrate with any server side presentation like Spring MVC.

Your server side should only return data in JSON format.

Comment: But we integrate it in xhtml page!! can you explain me please how to configure web.xml, spring mvc and webflow context  for handling my request ?!! because i found that all the examples handles the jsp page not html

Comment: Your 'bootstrap' html page has nothing to do with Spring. Load angular and your other js code in index.html (or index.jsp). This will be loaded by the web container's default servlet (file servlet), not by Spring's Dispatcher servlet.